# How can I check to see if a data set has a grouping of 3 entries within 5 days

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking to see if from a specific date there are a total of 3 entries within a grouping of 5 days within +/- 5 days of the specified date.  As long as the second column is false.

Here is an example data set.

```
Create Table #Data(entryDate date, complete bit)
Insert into #Data Values('2013-02-05', 1)
Insert into #Data Values('2013-02-06', 0)
Insert into #Data Values('2013-02-09', 0)
Insert into #Data Values('2013-02-11', 0)
Insert into #Data Values('2013-02-12', 0)
Insert into #Data Values('2013-02-14', 0)
```

Given a date of 2013-02-11 I want a true result given that there are 2 scenarios that satisfy my conditions.

1. 2013-02-09, 2013-02-11, 2013-02-12
2. 2013-02-11, 2013-02-12, 2013-02-14

Or given a date of 2013-02-09 I would get a true result but there is only 1 scenario that satisfies the conditions

1. 2013-02-09, 2013-02-11, 2013-02-12

Note that 2013-02-05, 2013-02-06, 2013-02-09 do not satisfy the conditions due to the fact that 2013-02-05 is set to true.

How can I write a sql expression that gives me true or false as described above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've also come up with the following which ensures that no dates after a completion are counted towards the 3 of 5 groupings

```
Declare @data table(Id int, entryDate date, complete bit)
Insert into @data Values(1, '2013-02-05', 1)
Insert into @data Values(2, '2013-02-06', 0)
Insert into @data Values(3, '2013-02-09', 0)
Insert into @data Values(4, '2013-02-11', 0)
Insert into @data Values(5, '2013-02-12', 0)
Insert into @data Values(6, '2013-02-14', 0)

Declare @windowMiddle date
Set @windowMiddle = '2013-02-09'

Declare @newestComplete date
select top 1 @newestComplete = entryDate from @data where complete =1 order by entryDate desc

--if(@newestComplete > @windowMiddle) --exit

;with cte  as
(
select * 
from @data  cte
where
    cte.entryDate > DATEADD(dd, -5, @windowMiddle) 
    and cte.entryDate >@newestComplete 
    and cte.entryDate < DATEADD(dd, 5, @windowMiddle)
)

select cte.entryDate, count(*)
from cte inner join cte d on cte.entryDate between DATEADD(dd, -4, d.entryDate) and d.entryDate
group by cte.entryDate
having (count(*)>=3)
```

Perhaps someone can comment on whether [BlackjacketMack's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21471078/1006095) is better than this.

Comment: Nothing wrong with getting the job done, so props to you for that!  But I would say this - Sql loves queries, and anytime you're setting variables and querying from them you're making it operate procedurally which is slow.  My query for instance, could easily be nested inside a bigger query so that you could even get multiple groups of the results by region.  And I think using OUTER APPLY is just generally a cleaner approach and easier to read once you know what's going on, and you can see the results (and query from them) across the whole dataset.

Answer (score 2):

use Outer Apply and then evaluate your result.

```
    declare @data table(entryDate date, complete bit)
        Insert into @data Values('2013-02-05', 1)
        Insert into @data Values('2013-02-06', 0)
        Insert into @data Values('2013-02-09', 0)
        Insert into @data Values('2013-02-11', 0)
        Insert into @data Values('2013-02-12', 0)
        Insert into @data Values('2013-02-14', 0)

select *
from @data d1
outer apply (
    SELECT Count(*) AS CountMatches

    FROM @data d2
    where
        ABS(DateDiff(d,d1.entryDate,d2.entryDate)) < 5 AND
        complete = 0 AND
        d1.entryDate <> d2.entryDate
) t
where
    t.CountMatches >=3
```

Comment: This doesn't quite solve my problem.  The entry date of the 9th is returning that it matches 4 entries however there are only 3 entries within 5 days of each other that match not 4.

Comment: @mark Change the `<= 5` to `< 5` because you are counting the current date too.

Comment: Got it...Your example in the question using 2013-02-09 confused me a little because your are including itself.  But for 2013-02-09, wouldn't 2013-02-14 be within the 5 day limit?  If so, then '<=', if you are not intending that, then use '<'.

Comment: Sorry I could have been more clear.  Including the 14th gives a 6 day spread, when I'm looking for any grouping of 3 within a 5 day spread of a specific date.

Comment: I see...inclusive/exclusive issue.  So you'd want '<' and you should be good.  I'll update the answer to not have the inclusive '<=5' and let me know if that answers the question.

Comment: Hmm I just played with this a bit more and it doesn't quite do what I was looking for. This query will get the count of items that match each date within a +/- spread.  However, what I need is a count of items(x) within 5 days of each other (y) within +/- (y) a date.

This query ends up getting a count x in 10 (y*2).